# How do you enable debug mode on SourceSync embeds?

Tags: embed

I'm trying to use their new overlay experience type on my own videos, but I can't get the Player.js messages to control it. I read they have a debug mode that shows the current play time and a bunch more stuff, but I don't have access to the distribution, only the embed link. Can I turn on debugging still?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Found it shortly after posting this. Putting it here as their docs don't seem to show up on Google. It's in their docs here: https://docs.sourcesync.io/#/embedding

You just add `debug=true` to their script. i.e.

`<script src="https://sourcesync.io/js/embed.js?debug=true"></script>`